# Is there any solution for "destination" error with NavMeshAgent in Unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, navigation, augmented-reality, vuforia

I'm working on "Indoor Navigation" using Vuforia in unity. I have scanned the map using "Vuforia Area Target Creator" and import area targets to Unity Project, then I have merged mulitple area targets as one area target, then I have Created NavMesh and NavMesh Agent, then I want to test if the NavMeshAgent move to destination or not. I'm following Unity Manual: https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/nav-MoveToDestination.html

When I wrote this script, I get this error: [image: Error]

My Script:

```
// MoveTo.cs
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.AI;
public class MoveTo : MonoBehaviour {
   
   public Transform goal;
   
   void Start () {
      NavMeshAgent agent = GetComponent<NavMeshAgent>();
      agent.destination = goal.position; 
   }
}
```

I also searched on Youtube, I found that someone wrote the same code for his game and working with him, What's the problem ??

Can any one help me in this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
private void Start()
{
    NavMeshAgent agent = GetComponent<NavMeshAgent>();
    agent.SetDestination(goal.position);
}
```

if you want to set your agent destination to the target than change your code like upon code.

Comment: Sorry for my late response because of network problems, thanks I have found the solution. My problem was that I created a Script file called "NavMeshAgent", so there are to 2 classes, the one of the my script and another is NavMesh class. I have renamed my script and it worked.

Comment: Can you help me how to make a list of destinations ( not only one ) that user choose one of them and application will guide to it ?